# how to block a statement from execution till the previuos has finished in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, logging

I have two lines :

```
   display.print(x); // outputs a collection contenet
   LOG.info("Total word count is completed.");
```

the method call in the first line prints a bunch of data from a collection. But while its printing and before finishing the log statement gets executed. So the output looks like:

```
...   
a : 6
as : 6
23/06/2012 09:38:01 م sample.testing
INFO: Processing... 0 thread(s) has/have finished
book : 6
had : 6
...
```

but the log should only be printed after all the data is printed. why this is happening? and how it can be solved?

that's the print method:

```
 public void print(Map<String, Integer> map)
{
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> current : map.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s : %d", current.getKey(), current.getValue()));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

edit 2:
I pass  `ThreadClass.getCol()`  to the print method. `ThreadClass.getCol()` returns a collection from ThreadClass where many threads update this collection. It's synchronized and i am returning a copy of it.

Comment: Incidentally, your sample output doesn't correspond to the code you've shown us...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth apologies for that, edited.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `outputter.print` fires off a thread (or maybe multiple threads), which is/are 
asynchronously writing to `System.out` (or wherever your text output is going).

The way to solve this is to wait until these threads have completed all their work.  As you haven't shown us the code for that method, I can't really help you with that!

Comment: the print method does not actually create any threads, it's just printing out values.

Comment: @Sam  in that case it's likely that two threads are calling this code at once, you need to synchronize.  See my answer.  (or else you just need to flush outputter)

Answer (score 0):

If @Oli Charlesworth is correct, and `outputter.print()` fires off a thread, we will need to see that code and find out how to wait for it to return.

Another possibility is that `outputter.print()` doesn't do anything fancy, but that two different threads are calling this code at once.  In that case, the simplest fix is to synchronize this code.  e.g., if it is in a method:

```
public **synchronized** void outputterPrint() {
   outputter.print(x); // outputs a collection contenet
   // you might want to add some sort of flush here
   outputter.flush();

   LOG.info("Total word count is completed.");
}
```

If this code gets called a skillion times this has performance issues.  But for infrequent calls this is safe and simple.

Answer (score 0):

outputter.print fires starts a porcess or a thread. If outputter.print(x) returns a Process, you could use .waitFor() to wait for the end. But its not enough information to answer your question. Perhaps theres a method which you tell, if its ready. If you wanna do a dirty trick, use
`Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000)`

But its not a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Try a flush operation on outputter after your print statement.

Answer (score 0):

there is a multi-threading issue though I can't be sure why cause you haven't placed your entire code. You could get your hands dirty by "getting" the appropriate thread and adding a NotifyAll() and then causing another thread to execute by waiting for this notification.

**OR** you could just place your

```
LOG.info("Total word count is completed.");
```

at the end of your print (...) method.

**Comment** if you want an abstract answer for your original question *"how to block a statement from execution till the previuos has finished in java?"*